# Angularjs delaying path change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and this is my attempt:

```
$scope.comparisonlist.forEach(function (script) {
     $http.get('/info/' + script.id)
         .success(function (data) {
              $scope.comparisonResultList.push(data)
          })
          .error(function (data, status) {
                console.error('Repos error', status, data);
           })

});

 $location.path('/comparison');
```

I am trying to change the path after  the http requests (AFTER THE LOOP OF REQUESTS), however what is happening her is that its changing the path before http request is done. I am not sure how to fix this. I tried using promise but it completely does not work

```
  <div ng-repeat="result in comparisonResultList">
```

With promise when I do this ^^ on top I get nothing, I am assuming it is dectecting comparisonResultList to be empty somehow

Answer (score 0):

The current promise implementation should work, calling the path change after every async operation in the forEach loop completes.

```
var promises = [];
$scope.comparisonlist.forEach(function (script) {
  promises.push($http.get('/info/' + script.id)
    .success(function (data) {
      $scope.comparisonResultList.push(data)
    })
    .error(function (data, status) {
      console.error('Repos error', status, data);
    })
  )
});
$q.all(prom).then(function () {
  $location.path('/comparison');
});
```

Comment: request is happening in a loop. I want all the requests to be done and then execute $location.path('/comparison'); @colonelsanders

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that until now. Edited my answer, I think $q is the best way to do this (without knowing how/why it broke your program before)

Comment: this one breaks to... when I say break I mean, in my html i am doing ng-repeat and that doesnt work when I do <div ng-repeat="result in comparisonResultList">

Comment: Does it work if you hardcode an array of data to `$scope.comparisonResultList`? If not, there is something else going on.

Comment: Last thing I got is to try forcing a view re-render: call `$scope.$apply();` right after the path change.